# MVC publish database changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I worked through the following tutorial ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674760/Code-First-Migration-and-Extending-Identity-Accoun?msg=4795559#xx4795559xx)) however I published to azure before adding the additional fields as per the second part of the tutorial. My problem is once I have added the new fields/properties I can't seem to get the migrations to work when publishing to Azure.

The tutorial suggests that you should drop the database but this is not practical in the real works when developing and extending an existing solution on a database that will have existing data.

And advice or pointers to suitable tutorials would be very much appreciated.

Cheers,
Kevin.

Comment: What exactly are you doing that is not working, and what error messages are displayed?  If you are publishing a website to Azure, are you selecting the option to run the database migration on deployment?

Comment: Once I have made the change in code to add the new fields to the local database using the update-database command I run the add-migration command and created a new migration file. I than published the project and made sure the the option to run migration was selected.

Comment: ...When I run the app I get "An error occurred while processing your request." message. When I check the database I can see the columns have not been created.

Comment: You may want to log the exception that is being generated in that case, and see what the underlying issue is.

Comment: Sorry I am new to asp and MVC. how do I log the excepting in azure?

Comment: Well, you could temporarily alter the error.cshtml page to show the exception message.